# ext call C# function from form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events, ext.net

When I use

```
<DirectEvents>
    <Click OnEvent="Button1_Click" />
</DirectEvents>
```

the `Button1_Click` function is export to Excel but it's not working.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    DBOperator db = new DBOperator();
    string sSql = "SELECT  * FROM table";
    DataTable dt = db.GetTable(sSql);
    ExcelHelper.ExportDTtoExcel(dt, "", "test.xls");
}
```

When I do not use ext is working.
aspx code :

```
<ext:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Title="人均情况" Width="900" Height="650">
    <Items>
        <ext:Button runat="server" Text="点EXT">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="Button1_Click" />
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>
    </Items>
```

I come from Chinese, English is very poor. I try to describe my problem.

I want to use the ext.net and NPOI (a EXCEL control) to export EXCEL files.

If I use the C# and NPOI work well.

Now I start using ext.net and NPOI. The following

```
<body>
    <form>
        My button
    </form>
</body>
```

It works.

But, as follows

```
<body>
    <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1"
                         runat="server"
                         Theme="Gray" / >
    <ext:Panel ID="Panel2"
               runat="server"
               Title="per capita"
               Width="900"
               Height="650">
        <Items>
            <ext:Button runat="server"
                        Text="EXT"
                        AutoPostBack="true">
                <DirectEvents>
                    <Click OnEvent="Button1_Click" / >
                </DirectEvents>
            </ext:Button>
        </Items>
    </ext:Panel>
</body>
```

It doesn't work.

Error:

> "WebForm_PostBackOptions" is not defined

When I removed `AutoPostBack= "true" >`

Error:

> error c00ce514 occurred due to the operation cannot be completed.

Above all, when I joined `ext:Panel` will error.

Comment: The answer to "it doesn't work" is "so fix it". If you won't tell us how it fails, how can we tell you anything specific? You need to take more care in your questions.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What is the relation with Excel and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably occurs with `ExcelHelper.ExportDTtoExcel`. I assume this Method is writing something to the Response stream, which overwrites the required Ext.NET DirectEvent Response.

The following sample demonstrates a technique for exporting to Excel during an Ext.NET DirectEvent:

http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Miscellaneous/Export_Data_Ajax/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your error occurs when your download code is placed inside an update panel performing an async postback?

Then you must ensure that the request delivering a binary file always performs a synchronous postback so that the browser is able to  interprete the binary result file.

**Solution:** Place the name of your Button as a [PostBackTrigger](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) or register the button with

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(yourButton)
```